# How to echoing the variable and loop?

Tags: php, html, loops, for-loop, echo

I want to make in  html page like this below:

```
<a href="1" class="currentvid"></a>
<a href="2"></a>
<a href="3"></a>
```

But, I don't want to write them all one by one, because the number(1, 2, 3) are from `$number` variable and it can be more than 3.

Comment: Then show us your current code which you have

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++) {
    echo "<a href='$i'";
    if ($i == $currentvid) {
        echo " class='currentvid'";
    }
    echo "></a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$href="1";
for($i=1;$i<4;$i++){
  if($href==$i){
   echo "<a href=\"$href\" class=\"currentvid\">$i</a>";
  }else{
   echo "<a href=\"$href\">$i</a>";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;
        foreach ($number as $k)
        {
            if($i == 1)
            {
                echo "<a href=\"$href\" class=\"currentvid\">$i</a>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<a href=\"$href\">$i</a>";
            }
        }
    }
```